# WebSockets connection

Tags: websocket

I recently had WebSockets running on my laptop with XSockets. I then had to rebuild my laptop, installed just like before, and now WebSockets don't work.

I have Norton Internet Security installed just like before. I looked at all my acive ports, checked out my firewall rules, what have ya, and I'm dead in the water. When I try to connect to my server, it immediately closes.

I dont know what else to check. I even turned off firewall protection from norton, and still it doesn't work.

Any help on what else to check, I surely would appreciate it. I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: Websockets don't work, or **your** websockets don't work? Do the ones at http://demo.hummingbirdstats.com/ work?

Comment: Have no idea. I'm simply connecting to a local socket server, and it immediately closes after trying to establish the connection. The socket sever starts fine. All settings look good but Im missing something. Somethingi s blocked somewhere. I just dont know what else to check.

Comment: You didn't answer my question... does the link I posted (which uses Websockets) work? Trying to figure out whether it 's server-side or client-side.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Yes it looke dlike the demo site is fine

Comment: OK, so it's something specific to your server. I'd look into server-side firewalls etc. Maybe your IP was whitelisted and changed when your laptop wasn't connected for a while?

Comment: @David: Is it on Chrome? They switched to a new draft version (hybi-08) with Chrome 14, which is just released.